# Libgdx - map shader to world

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader, mesh

I have a 2d level with box2d doing the physics. I have implemented the following [water effect](http://rotatingcanvas.com/fragment-shader-to-simulate-water-surface-in-libgdx/) described in this tutorial.  I am using one OrthographicCamera which is centred on the main character sprite.  The camera follows the sprite and as it reaches the edges of the level the camera stops moving. Currently the shader just renders the water along the bottom of the camera. My question is how would I go about rendering water along the bottom of the level instead so that when the sprite moves away from the bottom of the level the water "moves" offscreen?

```
public class GameRenderer {

private ImageProvider imageProvider;
private GameWorld world;
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
Vector2 camPos;
private Player player;
private Sprite itemPointer;
private Sprite playerSprite;
Sprite explosion;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
private Array<SimpleSpatial> mSpatials; // used for rendering rube images
private static final Vector2 mTmp = new Vector2();
private Map<String, Texture> mTextureMap;
private Map<Texture, TextureRegion> mTextureRegionMap;

//From tutorial
String vertexShader =
        "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n"
                + "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n"
                + "uniform mat4 u_worldView;\n"
                + "varying vec4 v_color;"
                + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;"
                + "void main()                  \n"
                + "{                            \n"
                + "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); \n"
                + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoord0; \n"
                + "   gl_Position =  u_worldView * a_position;  \n"
                + "}                            \n";

String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
        + "precision mediump float;\n"
        + "#endif\n"
        + "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture2;\n"
        + "uniform float timedelta;\n"
        + "void main()                                  \n"
        + "{                                            \n"
        + "  vec2 displacement = texture2D(u_texture2, v_texCoords/6.0).xy;\n" //
        + "  float t=v_texCoords.y +displacement.y*0.1-0.1+  (sin(v_texCoords.x * 60.0+timedelta) * 0.005); \n" //
        + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_texCoords.x,t));\n"
        + "}";

String fragmentShader2 = "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
        + "precision mediump float;\n"
        + "#endif\n"
        + "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
        + "void main()                                  \n"
        + "{                                            \n"
        + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n"
        + "}";


ShaderProgram shader;
ShaderProgram waterShader;

Matrix4 matrix;
float time;

Mesh waterMesh;

private Texture texture2;
private Texture texture3;

FPSLogger fpsLogger = new FPSLogger();


public GameRenderer(GameWorld gameWorld)  {

    imageProvider = GameManager.getInstance().getImageProvider();

    world = gameWorld;
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    camPos = new Vector2();

    loadBackgroundTextures();
    loadPlayerTextures();

    explosion = new Sprite(imageProvider.getExplosion());
    explosion.setScale(50  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX);

    setupCamera();

    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
}

public void show() {

    initGame();
}

private void initGame() {

    player = world.getPlayer();
    playerSprite = new Sprite(playerTexture);
    playerSprite.setScale(15  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX, 15  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX);

    createSpatialsFromRubeImages(world.getScene());

    initialiseShaders();

}

private void createSpatialsFromRubeImages(RubeScene scene)
{

    Array<RubeImage> images = scene.getImages();
    if ((images != null) && (images.size > 0))
    {
        mSpatials = new Array<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size; i++)
        {
            RubeImage image = images.get(i);
            mTmp.set(image.width, image.height);
            String textureFileName = image.file;
            Texture texture = mTextureMap.get(textureFileName);
            if (texture == null)
            {
                texture = new Texture(textureFileName);
                mTextureMap.put(textureFileName, texture);
            }
            SimpleSpatial spatial = new SimpleSpatial(texture, image.flip, image.body, image.color, mTmp, image.center,
                    image.angleInRads * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
            mSpatials.add(spatial);
        }
    }
}

    //From tutorial
public void initialiseShaders() {

    texture2 =new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/shaders/water.png"));
    texture2.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

    texture3 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/shaders/waterdisplacement.png"));
    texture3.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    texture3.bind();
    matrix = new Matrix4();


    ShaderProgram.pedantic=false;

    shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    waterShader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader2);
    waterShader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", matrix);

    waterMesh = createQuad();

    time=1f;
}

//From tutorial
public Mesh createQuad() {
    float[] verts = new float[20];
    int i = 0;

    verts[i++] = -1; // x1
    verts[i++] = -1; // y1
    verts[i++] = 0;
    verts[i++] = 1f; // u1
    verts[i++] = 1f; // v1 //

    verts[i++] = 1f; // x2
    verts[i++] = -1; // y2
    verts[i++] = 0;
    verts[i++] = 0f; // u2
    verts[i++] = 1f; // v2 //

    verts[i++] = 1; // x3
    verts[i++] = -0.3f; // y2
    verts[i++] = 0;
    verts[i++] = 0f; // u3
    verts[i++] = 0f; // v3

    verts[i++] = -1; // x4
    verts[i++] = -0.3f; // y4
    verts[i++] = 0;
    verts[i++] = 1f; // u4
    verts[i++] = 0f; // v4

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 0, // static mesh with 4 vertices and no
            // indices
            new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3,
                    ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE), new VertexAttribute(
            VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2,
            ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0"));

    mesh.setVertices(verts);
    return mesh;

}

private void setupCamera() {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(imageProvider.getScreenWidth(), imageProvider.getScreenHeight());
    camera.position.x = 500;
    camera.position.y = 500;

    camera.zoom = Constants.ZOOM_FACTOR;
    camera.update();
}

public void render(float delta) {

    spriteBatch.flush();

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    fpsLogger.log();


    Gdx.gl.glScissor(0, 0, (int)Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, (int)Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    drawBackground();
    updateCameraPosition();
    drawRest(delta);
    drawPlayer(delta);

    //Render water shader
    drawWater();

    debugRenderer.render(world.getRubeWorld(), camera.combined);
}

public void drawWater() {

    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    time += dt;
    float angle = time * (2 * MathUtils.PI);
    if (angle > (2 * MathUtils.PI))
        angle -= (2 * MathUtils.PI);

    //RENDER WATER
    Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);


    texture2.bind(1);
    texture3.bind(2);
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView",  matrix);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 1);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture2", 2);
    shader.setUniformf("timedelta", -angle);
    shader.setUniformf("v_texCoords.y", -10f );

    waterMesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    shader.end();

    Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    //Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);


}
public void drawBackground() {

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(parallaxCamera.combined);
    spriteBatch.draw(backgroundImage, parallaxCamera.position.x - 400, parallaxCamera.position.y - 240);
    spriteBatch.end();

}

public void drawRest(float delta) {

    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    spriteBatch.begin();

    //Renders Box2d world
    for (int i = 0; i < mSpatials.size; i++)
    {
        mSpatials.get(i).render(spriteBatch, 0);
    }

    spriteBatch.end();
}

public void drawPlayer(float delta) {

    if (!world.isGameOver()) {

        spriteBatch.begin();

        playerSprite.setOrigin(playerSprite.getWidth() / 2, playerSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        playerSprite.setPosition(world.getPlayer().getPosition().x - playerSprite.getWidth() / 2, world.getPlayer().getPosition().y - playerSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        playerSprite.setRotation(world.getPlayer().getDirection() - 90);
        playerSprite.draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.end();
    }
    else {

        spriteBatch.begin();
        explosion.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.end();

    }
}

private void updateCameraPosition() {

    camPos.lerp(world.getPlayer().getPosition(), 1.5f);

    if (camPos.x * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX < LEVELWIDTH && camPos.x  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX > 0) {

        camera.position.x = camPos.x;
    }

    if (camPos.y  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX < LEVELHEIGHT && camPos.y  * Constants.WORLD_TO_BOX > 0.75) {

        camera.position.y = camPos.y;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sending in the camera.combined matrix into u_worldView?

```
shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", cam.combined);
```

If you have some code snippets that would be very helpful.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a code sample of my GameRenderer class. As you can see I was passing in just a Matrix4 i.e : shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", matrix); I have edited it so that I now pass camera.combined however the shader does not render onscreen anywhere in the world.

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever find out what was going on? I thought this wasn't the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I thought it wasn't but after some mesh vertices being moved around, the line shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", cam.combined); was the key to getting the shader effect to stop following the camera (Possibly because I use the zoom and as my box2d world is tiny the main camera does not actually move).